# Ruby Watir from html instead of URL

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, watir, watir-webdriver, scrape

in my scenario i'm scraping a site whose content is generated by javascript. I know that watir is perfect for my situation, but as we all know, it tends to add a little overhead and make the program take a little longer.

Currently I am able to login using Nokogiri and sending a post request with username/password, as you can imagine this is really fast. After successful login I then go to an address where the content I want to scrape is located, and as I said before, such content is the result of some javascript processing, so Nokogiri is no good from this point.

What I want to do is use Watir to load the html already returned by Nokogiri so it parses all the javascript and then continue scraping the generated HTML without having to use Watir from the start to reduce processing time.

Is there a way to load content into Watir from an html String so it gets processed instead of invoking the 'goto' method?

Comment: Please read "[ask]", especially the links at the bottom. What has your research found? If you found nothing then show us where you searched and explain why those didn't help. Otherwise, what have you tried? As is your question is too broad and you're asking us to start from ground-zero and write a tutorial because we don't know what you have tried or haven't tried.

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't send post requests, are you talking about mechanize?  Your approach probably won't work because of XXS issues. Maybe you should consider loading mechanize cookies into watir.

Comment: @the Tin Man maybe if you dedicated your time to reading the questions instead of criticizing, you would notice the question is not broad at all: "is there a way to load content into watir from an HTML string instead so it gets processed instead of invoking the goto method?". Since there are other replies in accordance to the questions, it seems the question is clear

Comment: @pguardiario you are right, hadn't thought of XSS issues...

Comment: The answers being given are broad and generic, not specific and detailed. That's because there isn't enough required information being given. I'm not here to criticize, I'm here to help you get an answer, because I know what information is needed but also, because SO is about detailed answers that help others, not just you, we need information that helps others solve the problem too. And your question doesn't do that. And, since there are multiple down votes others feel the same way too.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is no. Watir is not designed to scrape web pages, but to test web pages. Testing web pages means navigating to them and interacting with them.

Additionally, if your html parser does not solve your problem, then copying text from that parser into Watir wouldn't fix your problem either.

Comment: Thanks. If I print the HTML output from Watir, the JavaScript generated code is present, so if I parse watir's output, my problem is solved

Comment: Yes, but you'd still need something with a javascript engine to *render the text, which means a browser, which means a website, either local or remote like boulder_ruby's suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'watir'
#previous stuff
`touch temp.html`
File.open("temp.html", "w") {|f| f.write(nokodoc.html)}
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto("file://#{Dir.pwd}/temp.html")
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's the pourpose of reading from a string: not having to save and Read a file